# Property 'matchImageSnapshot' does not exist on type 'cy & EventEmitter'

Tags: cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I configured the plugin as outlined (https://github.com/jaredpalmer/cypress-image-snapshot) but cypress does not recognize it. The plugin works if I add @ts-ignore in front of the line cy.matchImageSnapshot();, but I'd rather be able to configure the framework correctly so cypress doesn't complain.
Any idea?

index.js:

```
const cucumber = require('cypress-cucumber-preprocessor').default;
const browserify = require('@cypress/browserify-preprocessor');
const resolve = require('resolve');
const { addMatchImageSnapshotPlugin } = require('cypress-image-snapshot/plugin');

module.exports = (on, config) => {
    const options = {
        ...browserify.defaultOptions,
        typescript: resolve.sync('typescript', { baseDir: config.projectRoot })
    };
    on('file:preprocessor', cucumber(options));
    addMatchImageSnapshotPlugin(on, config);
};
```

commands.js

```
import { addMatchImageSnapshotCommand } from 'cypress-image-snapshot/command';
addMatchImageSnapshotCommand();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, You need to add `@types/cypress-image-snapshot` package for TypeScript type checking.

And then add `cypress-image-snapshot` in your `tsconfig.json`'s `compilerOptions.types` array.